# Import sql Dump with 2 Databases

Tags: mysql

I have a dump containing two databases. I created 2 emty databases called A and B.

Now I would like to import the two DBs inside the dump into those.

Is it possible with a command like this?

```
mysql -uroot -p12345678910  -e "A B < dump.sql"
```

How could I solve this most efficient?

Im getting "ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database. Is there a workaround when the dump contains 2 schemas?

Comment: Does dump.sql have instructions about database creating?

Comment: Im supposed to import it like this: mysql -uroot -p12345678910 -hlocalhost < "C:\sql\dump.sql" but im not able to do that remotely. I am however able to create schemas remotely. So Im looking for a workaround